# Symfony 2 architecture - best practices

Tags: php, symfony, architecture, uml, class-diagram

Now, im facing three issues about my symfony 2 application architecture using Doctrine 2. This is a one bundle application.

1. I will use some controllers of course, but I need some special controller "BeforeController" to be called before the others. In the "BeforeController" I want to place some initialize methods. Is it best practice to extends controllers by "BeforeController"?
2. I want to create some services in ServiceContainer. For every entity which I have, I want to create own service (e.g. There is Products entity, so I will create Product service, which provides methods manipulating with products and so on), if is it good way. Or is it in Controller compentence?
3. Can somebody explain me, what is in controller or in service competence?

I should like to create some logical and intuitive architecture. Maybe any class diagram should help me.

Can somebody describe me some best practices about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

1. [kernel.controller Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event), and example: [Before filters with the kernel.controller Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#before-filters-with-the-kernel-controller-event),
2. Service: [Service base info](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-service) and more: [What is a Service?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-service) [Controller base info](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-controller), and additionally [Action](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-action). It's nothing wrong with creating separate services for each entity if you really need it.
3. As above.

I recommended this video from SymfonyCon Warsaw 2013 [How Kris Writes Symfony Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pn2lYHvnoUQ#t=909).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. The first answer is comfortable, I was looking for something like this. I read your posts in second point already, but still i dont know, if i understand. Becouse in MVC, the controller should work with models (entities in this case). In my case are services which work with entities. So in controller, there are no queries like find(by, all)... If controller looking for some entity, it call some service, which return required entity using repository. Is it a good way?

Comment: It depends. If you want to use service (for entity) only for getting results you should rather use just `Repository`. And in your controller call sth like that: `$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:EntityName')->getSth($param1, $param2 ...)`. Of course you have to implement `getSth()` in your `EntityNameRepository`.

Comment: Services wouldnt for entity only. There should be another logic. Mainly, this classes(services) will be as dependencies to another class. Sorry, thats want i didnt mention. So I suppose, this is a good way, right?

Comment: So, in your case you could done that this way. But still you have to remember about keeping db management in your repository.  Btw. I've added video - please check this out.